# Why does MASS::lda behave non-deterministically?

Tags: r

I recently did some work in which I looked at the behaviour of lda in quite some detail, and I discovered that for observations close to the decision boundary predict.lda returns non-deterministic classes. Initially I thought it might be a numeric accuracy issue, but the projected data seem to be on the order of 1e-6 from the decision boundary, which is well above double precision.... I've written up a minimal(ish) example, see below:

```
# Fit an LDA model to a subset of Fisher's Iris data
x = as.matrix(iris[iris$Species != 'setosa', 1:4])
y = as.factor(as.character(iris[iris$Species != 'setosa', 'Species']))
m = MASS::lda(x, y)

# Generate data near the decision boundary
d = m$scaling
ord = order(x %*% d)
y.pred = MASS:::predict.lda(m, newdata = x)$class
ind = min(which(y.pred[ord] == 'virginica'))
# Interpolate between the two data points on either side of the decision boundary
s = seq(0, 1, length.out = 100001)
s = s[47479:47484] # Zoom on the decision boundary
x.test = (as.matrix(s) %*% t(x[ord[ind - 1], ])) + (as.matrix(1 - s) %*% t(x[ord[ind], ]))

# running predict.lda() on x.test seems to generate non-deterministic results.
# set.seed(123) # set.seed here seems to remove the non-determinism.
for (i in 1:10) {
  y.pred = MASS:::predict.lda(m, newdata = x.test)$class
  print(as.character(y.pred))
}
```

and in case it makes any difference, here is the sessionInfo output:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] MASS_7.3-51.4  compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `predict` method is finding ties, and it uses random selection to break them.  That's why setting the random seed makes it deterministic.

To find where the randomness is coming in, I edited a copy of `MASS:::predict.lda` to add in lines like this:

```
cat("after cl:"); print(rnorm(1)); set.seed(123); print(rnorm(1)); set.seed(123)
```

If the random number generator is used after this, the next value of `rnorm(1)` will be different than the one that follows directly after the `set.seed(123)` call.

Here's part of the edited source to `predict.lda` that illustrates the issue:

```
posterior <- dist/drop(dist %*% rep(1, ng))
cat("after posterior:"); print(rnorm(1)); set.seed(123); print(rnorm(1)); set.seed(123)

nm <- names(object$prior)
cl <- factor(nm[max.col(posterior)], levels = object$lev)
cat("after cl:"); print(rnorm(1)); set.seed(123); print(rnorm(1)); set.seed(123)
```

If you run that version, your loop will print text like this repeatedly:

```
after posterior:[1] -0.5604756
[1] -0.5604756
after cl:[1] 1.558708
[1] -0.5604756
[1] "virginica"  "virginica"  "versicolor" "virginica" 
[5] "versicolor" "versicolor"
```

And then if you look at the help for `max.col`, used in the `cl` calculation, you can see

> When ties.method = "random", as per default, ties are broken at
>   random. In this case, the determination of a tie assumes that the
>   entries are probabilities: there is a relative tolerance of 1e-5,
>   relative to the largest (in magnitude, omitting infinity) entry in the
>   row.

Comment: Good answer! Thank you!